# Find.replace with loop doesn't work the way I want

Tags: vba, ms-word

What I want to do:

1. Go through a document and look for word1
2. Replace word1 with word2
3. Change the word2 (increment it)
4. Do 1-3 until word1 is replaced everywhere

My code so far:

```
With ThisDocument.Range.Find ' search the Document
    .Text = "RS.0569/14.xxxxx" ' for this text
    .Replacement.Text = nextID ' replace it with an ID ( Start= 0 )
    Do ' loop the .execute part to increment my ID and only touch one ID at a time
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne ' only replace one word per loop
        nextID = Val(Split(nextID, ".")(2)) + 1 ' this is just ID+1
        nextID = "RS.0569/14.0000" + nextID ' put the ID together
        If Not .Found Then Exit Do ' Loop should stop if everything is replaced
    Loop

End With
```

Problem: The Loop only runs 1 time because the Boolean .Found doesn't work with the loop  -> I did "Debug.print .Found" before and after the .execute and the output was -> "False, True, True, False"

It looks like the .execute just switches the boolean which was False before but when the loop repeats the .execute it just switches it to "false" ( because it was true before)

Any idea? I have no idea for a workaround so I'm asking here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a little bit with word before, the `.Find` object is kind of tricky to work with especially because I do not do much Word automation, but I believe this should be working:

```
Dim fnd as Find
nextId = "RS.0569/14.00000"
Set fnd = ThisDocument.Range.Find
fnd.Text = "RS.0569/14.xxxxx"
Do
    nextId = Val(Split(nextId, ".")(2)) + 1
    nextId = "RS.0569/14.0000" & CStr(nextId) ' put the ID together
    fnd.Replacement.Text = nextId ' replace it with an ID ( Start= 0 )
    fnd.Wrap = wdFindContinue
    fnd.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne ' only replace one word per loop
Loop Until fnd.Found = False
```

It was trial & error, mostly; I think the `.Wrap` is what you need to allow it to continue.