# Word VBA Find and move on

Tags: vba, ms-word, find-replace

Here is my issue,
I'm looking for `":"` and typing HTML code with VBA. The code below keeps looping at the same `":"` and does not move on to the next, since I'm not actually removing it. Any suggestions?

```
Dim bFound As Boolean


bFound = True
Set r = ActiveDocument.Content

r.Find.ClearFormatting
Do While bFound
    With r.Find
        .Text = ":"
        .Replacement.Text = ":</b>"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        bFound = .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne, Forward:=True)
    End With

    If bFound Then
        r.Select
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.TypeText Text:="<b>"
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.MoveRight
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find.replace with loop doesn't work the way I want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497064/find-replace-with-loop-doesnt-work-the-way-i-want)

Comment: why not just replace all at once

Comment: @feelingunwelcome No, it's not a duplicate of that. There is quite likely a duplicate somewhere on the site, but that's not it.

Comment: @Slai Because the OP also wants to add content at the beginning of the line where the search term was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the code, which is otherwise quite good:

1. It uses `wdFindContinue` for the `Wrap` property, which means Find will restart at the beginning of the document. As a rule of thumb, always use `wdFindStop` in code.
2. It's necessary to move the found Range beyond that point if what's being searched remains in the document. This can be done by using `Range.Collapse`. Think of it like pressing the right-arrow key on the keyboard when you have a selection: it puts the cursor just beyond what was selected.

I've modified the original code with these two changes, plus I've declared a `Range`variable. That the original code ran without this declaration indicates `Option Explicit` may not be at the top of the code module. It's much better if it is there...

```
Sub JumpBeyondFound()
    Dim r As Word.Range
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    bFound = True
    Set r = ActiveDocument.content

    r.Find.ClearFormatting
    Do While bFound
        With r.Find
            .Text = ":"
            .Replacement.Text = ":</b>"
            .Forward = True
            .wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            bFound = .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne, Forward:=True)
        End With

        If bFound Then
            r.Select
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.TypeText Text:="<b>"
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.MoveRight
            r.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried, tested, works just fine. Thanks for the other suggestions as well.